# ignoring margin and float

Tags: html, css

I'm working on school project...So i'm building web site. But I have problem, after implementing laptop and lock simbol into HTML code CSS is ignoring any changes of float or margin in elements placed after those two simbols.. Any type of help will be apreachiated.

[Whole project folder - Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KtVS1ZNDAClQxp9DrELp2yyGToK_sMZf?usp=sharing)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="stil.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Thasadith" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <div class="container"> <img src="slike/glava.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="top-left">Logo</div>
    <div class="top-right">
      <div class="nav"> <a href="#section1">SERVICES</a> <a href="#section2">PORTFOLIO</a> <a href="#section3">ABOUT</a> <a href="#section4">CONTACT</a> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="centered">
      <p>Welcome To Our Studio!</p>
      <h1>IT'S NICE TO MEET YOU</h1>
      <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">TELL ME MORE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="services">
  <div class="main" id="section1"></div>
  <h2>SERVICES</h2>
  <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h6>
  <div class="services_slike">
    <article> <span><i class="fas fa-laptop"> </i> </span>
      <h3>Responsive Design</h3>
      <h7>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</h7>
    </article>
    <article> <span> <i class="fas fa-lock"></i> </span>
      <h3>Web Security</h3>
      <h7>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</h7>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main" id="section2">
  <h8>PORTFOLIO</h8>
</div>
<!--<div class="main" id="section3">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  <p>Click on the link to see the "smooth" scrolling effect.</p>
  <a href="#section1">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 2 Below</a>
  <p>Note: Remove the scroll-behavior property to remove smooth scrolling.</p>
</div>

<div class="main" id="section4">
  <h2>Section 5</h2>
  <a href="#section1">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 1 Above</a>
</div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
top-right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}
.nav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color: #E0CD36;
}
.nav a.active {
    color: #E0CD36;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
/* Top left text */
.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 150px;
    font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
    font-size: 50px;
}
/* Top right text */
.top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 130px;
    float: right;
}
/* Centered text */
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
headder {
    width: 98%;
    padding: 1%;
    float: right;
}
button {
    background-color: #FEC503;
    padding: 2%;
    color: white;
    width: 25%;
    border: none;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
}
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -1%;
    font-family: 'Thasadith', sans-serif;
}
span {
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-left: 28%;
}
h3 {
    margin-left: 24%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
h7 {
    color: #777777;
    margin-top: -1%;
    text-align: center;
}
article {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
h8 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.services_slike {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, in your html code in blocks article there element have h7. HTML didn't have that element. It has only h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 and h6. Here is right code.

```
<article> <span><i class="fas fa-laptop"> </i> </span>
      <h3>Responsive Design</h3>
      <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</h6>
    </article>
    <article> <span> <i class="fas fa-lock"></i> </span>
      <h3>Web Security</h3>
      <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</h6>
    </article>
```

Am I right understand you?

Answer (score 0):

From [Float on w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) for no float you can set **none** for float.

example :`float: none;`

and same as float, you can set **none** for every margin

```
margin-left:none;
```

if is not set for you, you can set **!important** for that style.